# How to find all items in a column that fit a criteria within another column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to find in the table scores, the student numbers that has all the grades in between 70 and 90. The answer should only return 105 and 108 since they are the only student numbers that fit the criteria. I keep getting 105,108, **and** 109 for some reason but I can't see why. This is the table below.

**SCORES**

```
sno | grade
101 | 64
109 | 68
105 | 75
109 | 76
108 | 78
107 | 79
108 | 81
101 | 85
NULL | 86
105 | 88
107 | 91
103 | 92
```

This is the query that is giving me that result.

````
SELECT sno                              
FROM scores
GROUP BY sno
HAVING grade BETWEEN 70 and 90;```
````

Comment: In the range 70 to 90, sno values are 105,  109, 108, 107....
Also what would happen for sno with multiple grade values?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after something like this:

```
SELECT sno, MIN(grade) as mingrade, MAX(grade) AS maxgrade 
FROM scores 
GROUP BY sno
HAVING MIN(grade) >= 70 AND MAX(grade) <= 90
```

but note that this will return the row that has a null value for "sno" because this row fits your criteria.  You can always add `WHERE sno IS NOT NULL` after the `FROM scores` if you want to exclude that row.

NOTE: Obviously you can leave out the mingrade/maxgrade columns if you don't wish to have them in the result set.

ADDITIONAL NOTE: I presume you are using SQLite?  Most other SQL dialects complain about the syntax in your example because they expect an aggregate function to apply on the columns used in the HAVING clause.

For what it's worth, there's an online demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=74e39f844331c5d98de217895593b00f)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
WITH OUTSIDE_GRADES
AS
(
SELECT SNO FROM SCORES
WHERE 1=1 
AND (GRADE < 70 OR GRADE > 90)
)
SELECT distinct SNO FROM SCORES WHERE SNO NOT IN (SELECT SNO FROM 
OUTSIDE_GRADES)
```

Comment: Your query has the same issue as the one in the question

Comment: Ok if the grades are 105 | 75

109 | 76

108 | 78

Sounds like all of them should be included since all the grades are between 70 and 90 am I wrong?

Comment: "the student numbers that has all the grades in between 70 and 90. The answer should only return 105 and 108 since they are the only student numbers that fit the criteria"

Comment: Ahh Ok I didn't see that there were repeat scores for a student. I'll change the query now.

Comment: Why `1=1` is there?

Comment: Whenever I’m coding with a WHERE clause I set it to start with a 1=1. This way the first statement is always true and if I need to comment out other AND statements later it’s much easier. It’s just a personal technique from years of coding and no really required other than my personal preference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224239/discussion-between-tdakers-and-mate-juhasz).